# How to use if statement in where condition in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to query the database as follows:

`User::where('type', 'student')->where('registered_at', '>=', $year)->get();`

if the user type is 'student' I want to get the registered from this year, however if the type is 'faculty' I don't want to have this 'registered_at' condition and want to execute this.

`User::where('type', 'faculty')->get();`

How to execute this so I have 1 query with kind of an if statement, if type is 'student' than give me only result above this `$year` and if type is 'faculty' give the results?

Comment: Do you want to get all users which are students with registered_at and all users with type faculty in one list?

Comment: @UfguFugullu Yes, I found the 'orWhere' clause can have a callback where I can have my conditions.

Comment: That's great, don't forget to mark the right answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses).

```
    User::where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('type', 'student')->where('registered_at', '>=', $year);
    })->orWhere(function($query) {
        $query->where('type', 'faculty');
    })->get();
```